# Add logs in for-each that not write in every iteration but in a configurable way

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to add logs in an already existing foreach in Java 7 that write not in every iteration but for example every 100k to avoid writing too much logs and to measure performance.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Stick your logs in some kind of (most likely in-memory) buffer, flush it at your desired interval. Maybe provide your attempts so far? This doesn't sound too tricky.

Comment: The question seems vague. Is there a compute operation in this loop? Do you plan to simply print a static string like `logging` or what exactly do you want to log?

Comment: Since it iterates millions of times, I mainly want to know the status of the iteration and how many iterations it has done. But if I print on each iteration the log file would get too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
    String data[] = {"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5"};
    int logLimit = 2;//Set this value according to your need like 100K
    int counter = 0;
    for (String d : data) {
        //Do your stuff
        counter++;
        if (counter == logLimit) {
            //Write your log
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
```